# Unit test project (.NET 7) is not compiling with a Xamarin.iOS project if both are in same solution

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-mac

If the unit test project (.NET 7) and Xamarin.iOS project is added in the same solution, the unit test project is not compiling with the following error.

[image]

IDE information

Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 for Mac
Version 17.5.5 (build 12)
Installation UUID: beaf4b9e-96c2-46f6-bcf7-9385e824efc9

Runtime
.NET 7.0.1 (64-bit)
Architecture: X64
Microsoft.macOS.Sdk 12.3.2372; git-rev-head:754abbf6a3563f6267e5717ae832b4ac25b1f2fb; git-branch:release/7.0.1xx-xcode13.3

Roslyn (Language Service)
4.5.0-3.23056.2+97881342e427ff5cdcba8f12b12ff8e6f3564431

NuGet
Version: 6.4.0.117

.NET SDK (x64)
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.302/Sdks
SDK Versions:
7.0.302
7.0.203
7.0.202
7.0.201
7.0.200
7.0.103
7.0.102
7.0.101
7.0.100
6.0.408
6.0.407
6.0.406
6.0.405
6.0.404
6.0.403
MSBuild SDKs: /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET Runtime (x64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
7.0.5
7.0.4
7.0.3
7.0.2
7.0.1
7.0.0
6.0.16
6.0.15
6.0.14
6.0.13
6.0.12
6.0.11

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.8.0.49
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Xamarin.Android
Version: 13.2.0.0 (Visual Studio Enterprise)
Commit: xamarin-android/d17-5/797e2e1
Android SDK: /Users/prabakaran/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
Supported Android versions:
12.0 (API level 31)
11.0 (API level 30)
13.0 (API level 33)

SDK Command-line Tools Version: 7.0
SDK Platform Tools Version: 33.0.2
SDK Build Tools Version: 33.0.2

Build Information:
Mono: 6dd9def
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/main@149d70fe
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.40.0@fdc1e34
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/main@9f02d77

Microsoft Build of OpenJDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk
11.0.16.1
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Eclipse Temurin JDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk
1.8.0.302
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager
Version: 17.5.0.33
Hash: f0c0c52
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-5~2
Build date: 2023-05-12 16:19:07 UTC

Android Device Manager
Version: 0.0.0.1245
Hash: 7f8a990
Branch: 7f8a990
Build date: 2023-05-12 16:19:07 UTC

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode: 14.3 21812
Build: 14E222b

Xamarin.Mac
Not Installed

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 16.4.0.6 Visual Studio Enterprise
Hash: 97731c92c
Branch: xcode14.3
Build date: 2023-04-11 22:38:36-0400

Xamarin Designer
Version: 17.5.3.47
Hash: e8b5d371c3
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-5
Build date: 2023-05-12 16:19:02 UTC

Build Information
Release ID: 1705050012
Git revision: 4bfbea94ce18d0c248460d1250770e8e90d3a2ff
Build date: 2023-05-12 16:17:20+00
Build branch: release-17.5
Build lane: release-17.5

Operating System
Mac OS X 13.3.1
Darwin 22.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0
Mon Mar  6 21:00:17 PST 2023
root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: Try unchecking 'Build with MSBuild on Mono' in Solution Properties - Build - General. When a solution contains a mix of classic Xamarin and .NET SDK style projects building with MSBuild on mono can fail. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-and-Restore-Errors-when-a-solution/10278382